# Weird piano chord on Police's Roxanne

Tags: rock, police

On the intro of the song [Police - Roxanne](https://youtu.be/3T1c7GkzRQQ?t=4) we can hear a weird piano chord (just before someone's laughing). The piano doesn't seem to feature elsewhere on the song.

Did they ask for a pianist to come and play just one chord? Is he credited?
Or is it unintentional, a blooper forgotten in the final mix?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out it was unintended and a fun fact.

In 2000, [Vic Gabarini](https://www.linkedin.com/in/vic-garbarini-706a0623) published in interview with the band, on [Revolver Magazine](http://www.revolvermag.com/). Here is an extract :

> **Revolver**: On *Roxanne*, the band's first big hit, there's a laugh followed by a weird piano chord in the beginning. What the hell was that all about?
>
> **Copeland**: Tell them what really happened, Sting. Tell them about that brilliant musical moment of yours.
>
> **Sting**: I was just about to sing the first line of this celebrated song when I noticed there was an upright piano next to the microphone. I was feeling tired - I'd been up all night for some reason - so **I just sort of sat down. I though the piano lid was closed, but it was open, so I wound up playing this incredible chord with my a$$. It was this atonal sort of cluster that went really nicely against the chords we were playing. We thought it was funny, so we left it in.**
>
> **Summers**: And real musicians can tell he's playing more from the left buttock than the right.

*Sources* : [The Police website](http://www.thepolice.com/news/revolver-69026), [Sting website](http://www.sting.com/news/title/revolver)