# Unwanted noises forgotten in the final mix

Tags: history

Inspired by [Weird piano chord on Police's Roxanne](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4350/weird-piano-chord-on-polices-roxanne), I am curious about other occurences of accidental unwanted noises that stayed forgotten in the final mix (like slammed door, sneeze, step noises...).

I would like to have sources that confirm it was first unententional, but they decided to let it or they never heard it until the track was released.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a list question, and such questions aren't a good fit for SE.

Comment: @BCdotWEB, I have seen such questions accepted when they define specific boundaries.

Comment: And no such boundaries exist here. How can there be one accepted answer to this question if multiple answers are submitted?

Comment: If the question is rephrased to say, for example "is there a term for such noises ? ", it satisfies the "single answer" criterion, while allowing comments to list instances.

Answer (score 4):

Found [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Music/comments/2sxwn0/what_famous_songs_have_mistakesstudio_glitches_in/) containing a quite considerable number of mistaken sounds left on songs.

Here are some examples of what can be found on this link:

John Bonham - Since I've Been Loving You

> John Bonham's squeaky kick drum pedal in "Since I've Been Loving You"

The Beatles - Hey Jude

> In the Beatles, Hey Jude, at 2:59 of the song, someone can allegedly be heard to say, "F****ng hell!"

Metallica - Master of Puppets

> In the Master of Puppets' (Metallica) solo, there's an accidental note that Kirk Hammett says he's hardly been able to replicate since. He accidentally bent the string off the fretboard.

The Rolling Stones - Satisfaction

> Rolling Stones - Satisfaction - Toward the end in the "and I try, and
>   I try, I can't get no" part, Keith cuts in too early with the first
>   note of the guitar riff. It's just a quick buzz of the guitar and then
>   he stops it when he realizes it's the wrong time.
>
> Source: Just listen to this part in both [the studio version](https://youtu.be/rz5wgNrUTVo) and a [live concert](https://youtu.be/g5W4k6vD2WY)

B-52 - Love Shack

> "TIIIIIIINNN ROOF! Rusted." from the B-52s' "Love Shack" was a mistake. It was originally supposed to be the start of a new verse or bridge or something, and Cindy Wilson came in singing it during recording, not realizing they were stopping where they were and recording that bit later.

Also, I know of a laughing at the end of the song Radio, recorded by Cash Cash for their debut álbum Take it to the Floor, but I can't tell wether it's left on purpose or not.

Comment: I think it was all done on purpose!

Comment: @Lucas, do you have sources that confirm all of these were inententional?

Comment: December was a busy month for me, so I could only try to find reliable sources last weekend, but no luck. I''l try again this weekend, but I don't suppose I'll have more luck this time.